# WorkManager's PeriodicWorkRequest is executing once and not repeating

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am trying to make use of WorkManager however I seem to be running into an issue where PeriodicSync is only repeated on startup once and that's it.

I've looked at this post [Is WorkManager's PeriodicWorkRequest really repeating for anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118515/is-workmanagers-periodicworkrequest-really-repeating-for-anyone) but there is no answer there. I am using the latest alpha build 10 as well.

If someone could help, it would be greatly appreciated. I am still new to android but need to get this to work for a project. I haven't even tried using it with the code I want but simply trying to get it to run correctly.

I set it to run every 10 seconds, I also tried 10,000 ms but neither worked and nothing happened after 10 seconds.

The Log message "Sync" only appears once onCreate and that's it.

<strike>Another issue I have is that every time I launch my app, it seems like the number of workers increases, as if they are getting added on top of each other and I don't know if that's related.</strike>
Answer to my other issue was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487305/workmanger-in-android-is-executing-dowork-more-than-once/52489956#52489956) but I still need help with my primary issue.

Here's my code:

The Worker Class

```
public class MyWorker2 extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "BOOGABOOGA";

    public MyWorker2(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {

        // Do the work here--in this case, compress the stored images.
        // In this example no parameters are passed; the task is
        // assumed to be "compress the whole library."
        Log.i(TAG, "Sync");

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return Result.SUCCESS;

    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PeriodicWorkRequest syncWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker2.class, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(syncWork);

    }
}
```

Edit: Reason this isn't working is because minimum interval to repeat a task is set to 15 minutes per the spec found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest

Comment: The minimum interval time for periodic task is 15 min.

Comment: Yep, someone else just pointed out the same thing... I feel like such a fool.
Here is the spec: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest


My intention was to never use it every 10 seconds but I just tried that for testing purposes.

Comment: wont fire even once on me, I have 15 minutes interval. Testing on Oreo and Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Reason this wasn't working was because the minimum time interval where a task can be repeated is set to 15 minutes. Credit goes to [exshinigami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1490418/exshinigami). The spec for this can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#min_periodic_interval_millis

I just tested and verified that it did indeed repeat after 15 minutes.

Comment: I have 15 minutes interval and still not woking.

Comment: @ralphgabb Did you find anything about it. In my case it's not working even with 30 minutes interval

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal use alarm manager instead and not work manager, for some reason, work manager does not work on some devices in my experience.

Comment: You saved my day, ty